# tool to select wireless network at boot time in freebsd?

Tags: wireless-networking, freebsd

I routinely connect to different networks at work, home etc. currently I'm managing these via wpa_supplicant. I'm on freebsd9 (CURRENT)

I'm wondering if there is a way to use some sort of interactive menu to select what network I want to try to connect to during boot

in arch Linux, the `netcfg-menu` tool solves this

is there any similar tool for freebsd?

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to choose by hand, try the `net-mgmt/wifimgr` port.  I haven't used it myself, but this [FreeBSD Forums thread](http://forums.freebsd.org/showthread.php?t=2615) suggests it.

But really, if you want it to "just work" (by selecting the right network, in a context-aware fashion), you can use this idiom in `/etc/rc.conf[.local]`:

```
ifconfig_myint0="DHCP WPA"
```

(where `myint0` is your wireless network interface).

This will automatically connect you to networks listed in your wpa_supplicant config.